# Select Max difference between two dates in the same column

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, aggregate-functions, date-arithmetic

I have a table of accident date I want to calculate the maximum between the difference of date i and date i + 1 which are in the same column. when we declare an accident date, I want to find the record of days without accidents.

[image]

Comment: Please provide more info about the source table/ groupings/ business logic etc. How you’re describing it sounds like you want to find the difference between the MIN value and MAX value in the column, but presumably it’s the min and max values for each specific record - how is that defined - eg accident_id or something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lag()`. Assuming a table structure like `mytable(dt)`, where `dt` is of a `date`-like datatype, you would do:

```
select max(diff)
from (select dt - lag(dt) over(order by dt) diff from mytable) t
```